# Monthly recur with PHP

Tags: php, date

I have a two dates. start date and end date. Using those dates i have to find recur dates.

example:

```
(1) start date = 2014-01-01
    end date = 2014-05-01

    expected output:

        2014-01-01
        2014-02-01
        2014-03-01
        2014-04-01
        2014-05-01

(2) start date = 2014-01-31
    end date = 2014-05-01

    expected output:

        2014-01-31
        2014-02-28
        2014-03-31
        2014-04-30
```

> means do not skip month, if month is skip in that case use last day of month. how to achive this thing?

I am using following code but i added 1 month in date so it skip the month:

```
$start = strtotime($start_date);
$end = strtotime($end_date);
$total_dates = array();
for($i=$start; $i<=$end;)
{
    $date = date('Y-m-d',$start);
    if($i>$start)
    {                
        $next_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date . "+1 month"));   
        $start = strtotime($next_date);                                
    }
    else
    {
        $next_date = date('Y-m-d',$start);
    } 
    $total_dates[] = $next_date;

    $date1 = new DateTime($date);
    $newdate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date . "+1 month"));
    $date2 = new DateTime($newdate);

    $diff = $date2->diff($date1)->format("%a");
    /* Find diff between two dates */
    $i = (($i*1)+(86400*$diff));  //seconds in 1month
}
print_r($total_dates);
```

so in short:

```
start date = 2014-01-01
end date = 2014-05-01

expected output:

2014-01-31
2014-02-28
2014-03-31
2014-04-30

current output:

2014-01-31
2015-03-03
2015-04-03
```

Answer (score 1):

check this

```
$start_date = '2015-01-31';
$end_date  = '2016-06-01';
$start_date=date('Y-m-1', strtotime($start_date));
$diff = abs(strtotime($end_date) - strtotime($start_date));
$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));

if($years>0){$loop=$years*12+$months;}else{$loop=$months;}

for($i=1; $i<=$loop+1;$i++)
{


    $total_dates[] =$a= date('Y-m-t', strtotime($start_date));
    $start_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($start_date . "+1 month"));

}
print_r($total_dates);
```

//output  
 `Array ( [0] => 2015-01-31 [1] => 2015-02-28 [2] => 2015-03-31 [3] => 2015-04-30 [4] => 2015-05-31 [5] => 2015-06-30 [6] => 2015-07-31 [7] => 2015-08-31 [8] => 2015-09-30 [9] => 2015-10-31 [10] => 2015-11-30 [11] => 2015-12-31 [12] => 2016-01-31 [13] => 2016-02-29 [14] => 2016-03-31 [15] => 2016-04-30 [16] => 2016-05-31 [17] => 2016-06-30 )`

Comment: Thanks for ur answer.. but check ur code with this start date `2015-01-31`..this will skip the feb month.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<?php
$start_date = "2014-01-01";
 $end_date = "2014-05-01";
$d = date_parse_from_format("Y-m-d", $start_date);
 $start= $d["month"];

$d1 = date_parse_from_format("Y-m-d", $end_date);
 $end= $d1["month"];
 $array=array();
 $array[]=date('Y-m-t', strtotime($start_date));
for($i=$start;$i<$end;$i++)
{
$str=explode("-",$start_date);

$mon=$str[1]+$i;
 $newdate=$str[0]."-".$mon."-".$str[2];
 $array[]=date('Y-m-t', strtotime($newdate));
}

print_r($array);

output:

2014-01-31
2014-02-28
2014-03-31
2014-04-30
2014-05-31
```

Comment: Thank you for ur answer, but it is not working.. what if start date is `2014-12-01`

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP date/time functions with relative interval formats:
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

You can provide intervals like "last day of next month" or "last sat of July 2008", adding/subtracting this interval from the referenced date.